# SQL Query only returns one row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employee_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boss_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `department_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`department_id`)
);
```

Here's the dataset:

```
INSERT INTO `employees` (`employee_id`, `department_id`, `boss_id`, `name`, `salary`)
VALUES
    (1,1,0,'manager','80000'),
    (2,1,1,'emp1','60000'),
    (3,1,1,'emp2','50000'),
    (4,1,1,'emp3','95000'),
    (5,1,1,'emp4','75000');

INSERT INTO `departments` (`department_id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'IT'),
    (2,'HR'),
    (3,'Sales'),
    (4,'Marketing');
```

---

Exercise question: List employees who have the biggest salary in their departments.

Here's my query:

```
select e.name as 'employee name',max(e.salary) as 'salary',d.name as 'dept name'
from employees e join departments d
on e.department_id=d.department_id
group by d.name
```

Why does my query only return one row?  Shouldnt it return 4 (one per dept name)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All employees are in department 1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you think it's doing. The problem is that your data isn't what you think it is. The department_id for all entries in the `employees` table are the same, `1`. So you are getting one value per department, the problem is that only one department is represented.

Here's a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3860f/1) to illustrate this. I've augmented your schema but kept the query unmodified.

Comment: Probably a stupid question: Why is only one department represented?

Comment: Uh... you tell me? It's your data. By "only one department is represented," I was talking about your `employees` table. In your insert statement, all the `department_id`s are `1`. This is what I mean by "only one department is represented." You have no employees from other departments in the example you gave us. When I added them, the other departments appeared in the query output as you'd expect.

Comment: Even if all employees have an employee_id of 1, shouldn't it still give me 4 rows (since I'm grouping by d.name (and there are 4 distinct names)? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Reference Andomar's answer. When you inner join, you will only receive records that match the join condition. The other departments don't have corresponding records in the employees table to match on, so no other departments appear. The alternative is to use an outer join, which will return 'null' `employees.name`s and `max(salary)`s for departments that don't appear in the employee table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 d.name,
 e.name,
 e.salary
FROM employees e
INNER join departments d on e.department_id=d.department_id
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
    d.department_id,
    max(e.salary) as salary
   from departments d 
   left join employees e on e.department_id=d.department_id
   group by d.department_id
) x ON x.salary = e.salary AND d.department_id = x.department_id
```

This query will return the employees list with max salary in each department. And if you want to see an info for more than one department - just fill up another departments with more employees (according to your statements, you have an employees only in the department with department_id = 1)

Answer (score 0):

An `inner join` returns only rows for the `on` condition matches.  Since only one department has employees, only that department will be returned.

To select all departments, use a `left join`:

```
select  e.name as 'name of a random employee'
,       max(e.salary) as 'max salary'
,       d.name as 'dept name'
from    departments d 
left join 
        employees e
on      e.department_id=d.department_id
group by
        d.name
```

Note that if you use a column that's not in a group by (like `e.name` above) you essentially get a random value.  It won't always return the name of the employee with the highest salary.

To return the name of the employee with the highest salary, you could:

```
select  e.name as 'name of a employee with max salary'
,       e.salary as 'max salary'
,       d.name as 'dept name'
from    departments d 
left join 
        employees e
on      e.department_id=d.department_id
where   e.name is null
        or e.salary =
        (
        select  max(salary)
        from    employees e2
        where   e.department_id = e2.department_id
        )
```

Comment: And still the query is wrong. The question is : List employees who have the biggest salary in their departments, but your query will not return an employee names, only max(salary).